# Mechanical solution for keeping a vertical stack under pressure

Tags: mechanisms, mechanical

I'm looking for a solution for keeping a vertical stack of small boxes under tension. I will use the device in the attached picture to hold the boxes which will have a lid on the top, and the boxes will be pushed towards the front by a linear actuator. So far I've thought of an extension spring which will be attached to the back end of the device and the bottom platform, but not sure if it's an optimal solution.

[image]

Thanks,
George

Comment: Pressure and tension are not the same. Do you mean compression not tension? Won’t gravity be sufficient ie the mass of the boxes above?

Comment: Gravity would work if I would take them out at the bottom of the stack, but I'm trying to get them out at the top of the stack so I would need to have the stack pushed against the top lid at all the times. I could use a compression string at the bottom to push the stack up, or an extension string to pull it up.

Comment: So when you say “pushed to the front” that is where?

Comment: The front is the right hand side of the device(the smaller one in height). I'm sorry that the picture and my question are not self explanatory :(

Comment: How will you stop or control the upward movement? Because any spring capable of lifting 20 boxes will just continue moving when there is only 10. What about a screw or helix - think of the canned drinks dispensers... why not work with gravity instead of against it? Putting some labels on your image may help... I thought that black thing bottom left was the ouput flap...

Comment: I've added an edited pic. The boxes will be stacked on the black thing, and should be pushed vertically against a top lid which does not appear in the initial picture. A linear actuator will push the top box towards the front. I'm trying to get it out on the top as if I would take it from the bottom part, I would still require some sort of a lift mechanism to pull it back up.

Comment: How dense are these boxes? (how much smaller than a box would you be able to make a counterweight with the same mass?)

Comment: The boxes are made from cardboard, they measure about 90*90mm and 25mm in height and they're pretty stiff. They would weigh about 50 grams each.